# Sort object array with objects that are not quite the same using two different sort conditions

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
/*
        I have two people
*/

var person_one= 'person_one';
var person_two= 'person_two';

/*
    This is a response I get from a server
*/

var response = [
{"key":{"name":"person_one","kind":"attrA","path":["attrA","person_one"]},"data":{"q":"3","n":"0"}},
{"key":{"name":"person_one","kind":"attrB","parent":{"name":"person_two","kind":"attrA","path":["attrA","person_two"]},"path":["attrA","person_two","attrB","person_one"]},"data":{"some_data":"p"}},
{"key":{"name":"person_two","kind":"attrA","path":["attrA","person_two"]},"data":{"q":"1","n":"0"}}
];

/*
    Sort the object array by the key.kind field. So all attrA will come first and then attraB
*/

function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.key.kind < b.key.kind )
    return -1;
  else if (a.key.kind  > b.key.kind)
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
}

response.sort(compare); //sort

console.log('Sorted response = ' + JSON.stringify(response) ); //print sorted response
```

This is the code I have so far. What is happening is I get a response from the server which is:

```
[
{"key":{"name":"person_one","kind":"attrA","path":["attrA","person_one"]},"data":{"q":"3","n":"0"}},
{"key":{"name":"person_one","kind":"attrB","parent":{"name":"person_two","kind":"attrA","path":["attrA","person_two"]},"path":["attrA","person_two","attrB","person_one"]},"data":{"some_data":"p"}},
{"key":{"name":"person_two","kind":"attrA","path":["attrA","person_two"]},"data":{"q":"1","n":"0"}}
]
```

I need to now sort this response using two following conditions:

- The first condition is to sort it by the key.kind attribute which the code does. All `attraA` will need to show first, then `attraB`
- The second condition is after this is sorted by key.kind it then needs to sort it by name. So that person_one will always come before person_two (these are just fake names to show the concept, but actual names could be like jack or jill, etc). So I am able to sort by key.kind, but I am unsure how to add a second sort condition now and sort it by it. If this was SQL it would be similar to something such as this: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY KIND,NAME; -- sort by KIND first then NAME`

Comment: You might want to remove unnecessary details from your question. What does the code you "have so far" to do with your question? Also, 

    `var person_one= 'person_one'; var person_one = 'person_two';`

should probably be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your server response is stored within array `people`. Then you can use the [Array sort() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) with a user defined compare function:

```
people = people.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.key.kind != b.key.kind) return a.key.kind > b.key.kind;
    else return a.key.name > b.key.name;
});
```